# Understanding of vue-router and data properties

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a situation where when I navigate to a route, my computed property updates and updates my view accordingly. When I switch to another route and back - I lose all my data that is assigned in the this scope. I'm using created to initialize these variables, and then navigate back they reinitialize to a null state.

In my computed property, I populate these other (created variables) and those are used in the view.

My question is - is the reinitializing normal?  Am I going about this incorrectly?

```
    created: function() {
            this.abc = {};
    },
    computed: {
        myData: function() {
            return this.$store.state.myData;
        },
        setupData: function() {
            console.log('only update now!')
            var myData = this.myData;

            //doSomething that updates this.abc
        }
     },
     watch: {
        myData: {
            handler: function(newValue) {
                this.setupData(newValue);
            },
            deep: true
        }
    },
```

Comment: Yes, that's expected behavior. Whenever you route to a new component, that component is created and the previous route's component is destroyed. http://jsfiddle.net/yqtgpapd/

Comment: @thanksd So I'm confused.  If I have a computed property that updates accordingly.  And then from that property I filter out certain criteria and display it in the view via a different variable.  How do I go about doing this if it clears everytime but the computed property is populated?

Comment: You haven't explained your issue enough or shared enough code to know what you expect to happen and what you're actually experiencing. Does the provided answer not work for you? Please elaborate

Comment: I'm trying to understand what is the proper way of approaching this.  My data store is an ajax call that gets initiated on app load.  Once this ajax call is completed, it populate a state variable.  Let's call it abc.  In my component - I have the properties above.  On first load - setupData gets called and I'm good to go.  When I renavigate back to this route, setupData doesn't get called since abc was not updated.  My setupData takes this.abc and splits it out into 2 arrays and i display them in my view seperately. These variables are null when going back and same when using keep-alive.

Comment: Strike that. keep-alive works.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the re-initialization is normal. If you want to keep your component, use the [keep-alive tag](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#keep-alive):

> If you want to keep the switched-out components in memory so that you
> can preserve their state or avoid re-rendering, you can wrap a dynamic
> component in a  element:

```
<keep-alive>
  <component :is="currentView">
    <!-- inactive components will be cached! -->
  </component>
</keep-alive>
```

The documentation about the `<router-view>` also [refers to it](https://router.vuejs.org/en/api/router-view.html):

> Since it's just a component, it works with `<transition>` and `<keep-alive>`.

Comment: Dang nabit! Beat me to it.

Comment: cello @Kano This worked - one issue I'm seeing is as I switch between routes I started seeind the the views append at the bottom to each other.  Ever seen this?  I'm trying to see if this some other piece of code unrelated thats causing this but just wanted to see your thougts.